# Pivot columnas dinamicas sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

quisiera que me puedan ayudar, tengo una tabla que tiene los siguientes campos(imagen 1):

- **HCODSEC, HCODUSUAT,HFECPRO,HCODOPE,HSALCAPMN,HSALVENMN**

Quisiera convertirlo a pivot de la siguiente Manera Imagen 2 ,
estaba realizando con pivot pero no tengo el mismo resultado, la query que estaba haciendo es esta: , pero no puedo hacer a lo de la imagen 2 , si alguien me pudiera ayudar.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
       @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(HFECPRO) 
               FROM storage.[com_act].VCAUT001  
               FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
               ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
           ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT HCODSEC, HCODUSAUT, HCODOPE,' + @cols + ' from 
               (
                   select HFECPRO,HSALVENMN,HCODSEC, HCODUSAUT, HCODOPE
                   from storage.[com_act].VCAUT001 
              ) x
               pivot 
               (
                    max(HSALVENMN)
                   for HFECPRO in (' + @cols + ')
               ) p '


exec(@query)
```

**Imagen 1**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Imagen 2

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno lo que realizo fue lo siguiente es agregarlo en cada cte diferente y las cabeceras cambiarlo de nombre y hacer un inner join así:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),@colsx AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
       @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(RFEC) 
               FROM mod_rep.[piv].[FEXTFEC01](eomonth(getdate(),-1),'{"set":"auto"}')
               FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
               ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
           ,1,1,'')


select @colsx = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(cast(RFEC as varchar(250)))+'AS '+QUOTENAME(cast(RFEC as varchar(250))+'_HSALVENMN') 
               FROM mod_rep.[piv].[FEXTFEC01](eomonth(getdate(),-1),'{"set":"auto"}')
               FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
               ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
           ,1,1,'')


set @query = ' with a as (
              SELECT HCODSEC, HCODUSAUT, HCODOPE,' + @cols + ' from 
               (
                   select HFECPRO,HSALCAPMN,HCODSEC, HCODUSAUT, HCODOPE
                   from storage.[com_act].VCAUT001   WITH (NOLOCK )
              ) x
               pivot 
               (
                    sum(HSALCAPMN)
                   for HFECPRO in (' + @cols + ')
               ) p 
               ),
               b as (
                SELECT  HCODOPE as HCODOPE_HSALVENMN,' + @colsx + '  from 
               (
                   select HFECPRO,HSALVENMN,HCODSEC, HCODUSAUT, HCODOPE
                   from storage.[com_act].VCAUT001 WITH (NOLOCK )
              ) y
               pivot 
               (
                    sum(HSALVENMN)
                   for HFECPRO in (' + @cols + ')
               ) p 
               ),
               c as (
                select *
                from A
                inner join b 
                on a.hcodope=b.HCODOPE_HSALVENMN
               )
               insert into #CarteraPivot
               select *   from c
               '               

exec(@query)
```